# Evaluate a list of functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

I have a list of functions which have no side-effects and take the same arguments. I need to evaluate each function in my list and put the results into another list. Is there a function in Clojure that does it?

Comment: If you mean that you want to apply each function to the same arguments, you only need a suitable function to `map` over the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(map #(% arg) function-list)
```

Should do the job?

Answer (score 6):

[`juxt`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt) should do it:

```
((juxt inc dec) 1)
=> [2 0]
```

(If you literally have a list of functions and you want a list of results, do `(apply list ((apply juxt (list inc dec)) 1))`, as indicated in the comments.)

Comment: And if you have the functions in a sequence, you have to `apply` the list to `juxt` function as usual: `((apply juxt [inc dec]) 1)`

Comment: Be careful, `(into '() ...)` will reverse the order!  Better to just omit the `into` or replace it with `doall` if you need eager evaluation.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. Neither of those returns a list, though, but  `apply list` will fix it. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(map apply [+ - * /] (repeat [1 2 3 4]))
=> (10 -8 24 1/24)
```